# Write to a Google spreadsheet with a custom form

Tags: php, google-sheets

This is the code im using for my "email and add data to form" php back-end script, for some reason I can't change the first five cells to the Name, Email, Timestamp, Order, Total Price needed to add the form data. I also am trying o figure out how to make a new sheet for each name so that each persons orders go on their own page. Some of this code used to be handled by Zend but that framework is no longer supported. I'm in a bit over my head, can you guys help?

```php
 // set credentials for ClientLogin authentication
 $user = "My username";
  $pass = "My Pass";
// set target spreadsheet and worksheet
$ssKey = 'Order';
   $wsKey = '$name';

  // update cell at row 1, column X
$entry = $service->updateCell('1', '1', 'Name', $ssKey, $wsKey);
$entry = $service->updateCell('1', '2', 'Email', $ssKey, $wsKey);
$entry = $service->updateCell('1', '3', 'Timestamp', $ssKey, $wsKey);
$entry = $service->updateCell('1', '4', 'Order', $ssKey, $wsKey);
$entry = $service->updateCell('1', '5', 'Total Price', $ssKey, $wsKey);

include 'spreadsheet.php';
$Spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet($user, $pass);
$Spreadsheet->
setSpreadsheet($wsKey)->
setWorksheet($wsKey)->
add(array("Name" => "$name", "Email" => "$visitor_email", "Timestamp" =>  "$datevalue", "Order" => "$sandwich, $sandwichside, $salads, $beverages", "Total Price" => "\$$TotalPrice"));
```

The Speadsheet.php is this:

```php
<?
#from php-form-builder-class
class Spreadsheet {
private $token;
private $spreadsheet;
private $worksheet;
private $spreadsheetid;
private $worksheetid;

public function __construct($username, $password) {
    $this->authenticate($username, $password);
}

public function authenticate($username, $password) {
    $url = "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin";
    $fields = array(
        "accountType" => "HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE",
        "Email" => $username,
        "Passwd" => $password,
        "service" => "wise",
        "source" => "pfbc"
    );
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($curl);

    if($status == 200) {
        if(stripos($response, "auth=") !== false) {
            preg_match("/auth=([a-z0-9_\-]+)/i", $response, $matches);
            $this->token = $matches[1];
        }
    }
}

public function setSpreadsheet($title) {
    $this->spreadsheet = $title;
    return $this;
}

public function setSpreadsheetId($id) {
    $this->spreadsheetid = $id;
    return $this;
}

public function setWorksheet($title) {
    $this->worksheet = $title;
    return $this;
}

public function add($data) {
    if(!empty($this->token)) {
        $url = $this->getPostUrl();
        if(!empty($url)) {
            $headers = array(
                "Content-Type: application/atom+xml",
                "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=" . $this->token,
                "GData-Version: 3.0"
            );

            $columnIDs = $this->getColumnIDs();

            if($columnIDs) {
                $fields = '<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gsx="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended">';
                foreach($data as $key => $value) {
                    $key = $this->formatColumnID($key);
                    if(in_array($key, $columnIDs))
                        $fields .= "<gsx:$key><![CDATA[$value]]></gsx:$key>";
                }
                $fields .= '</entry>';

                $curl = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
                $response = curl_exec($curl);
                $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
                curl_close($curl);
            }
        }
    }
}

private function getColumnIDs() {
    $url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/" . $this->spreadsheetid . "/" . $this->worksheetid . "/private/full?max-row=1";
    $headers = array(
        "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=" . $this->token,
        "GData-Version: 3.0"
    );
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($curl);

    if($status == 200) {

        $columnIDs = array();
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
        if($xml->entry) {
            $columnSize = sizeof($xml->entry);
            for($c = 0; $c < $columnSize; ++$c)
                $columnIDs[] = $this->formatColumnID($xml->entry[$c]->content);
        }               
        return $columnIDs;              
    }

    return "";
}

private function getPostUrl() {
    if (empty($this->spreadsheetid)){

        #find the id based on the spreadsheet name

        $url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full?title=" . urlencode($this->spreadsheet);
        $headers = array(
                        "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=" . $this->token,
                        "GData-Version: 3.0"
        );
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        if($status == 200) {
            $spreadsheetXml = simplexml_load_string($response);
            if($spreadsheetXml->entry) {
                $this->spreadsheetid = basename(trim($spreadsheetXml->entry[0]->id));
                $url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/" . $this->spreadsheetid . "/private/full";                                            
                if(!empty($this->worksheet))
                    $url .= "?title=" . $this->worksheet;

                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                $response = curl_exec($curl);
                $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
                if($status == 200) {
                    $worksheetXml = simplexml_load_string($response);
                    if($worksheetXml->entry)
                        $this->worksheetid = basename(trim($worksheetXml->entry[0]->id));
                }
            }
        }
        curl_close($curl);
    }


    if(!empty($this->spreadsheetid) && !empty($this->worksheetid))
        return "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/" . $this->spreadsheetid . "/" . $this->worksheetid . "/private/full";

    return "";
}

private function formatColumnID($val) {
    return preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9.-]/", "", strtolower($val));
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions in attached `Speadsheet.php` contain only **add new** values to existing preformated (like headers u manually create via web interface)  google doc (+ some initial ops like connection and authenticate to google docs). Seems like you look for `an extended` functionality, which this `spreadsheet.php` not provides...